# App that can use my Android phone as a webcam on my PC, but stream it in 4K over USB?

Tags: android, camera

I want to use my Galaxy Note 3 as a webcam. I thought why not, since it has a really good camera, which can record in 4K easily. A good thing about the phone, is that it comes with USB 3.0 (first and only phone?). However, newer phones with USB Type-C should be able to deliver a video stream in 4K easily as well.

So here's my question. Are there any apps out there, which can stream my Android phone's camera to my Windows PC, but show it at 4K resolution with highest bitrate possible? So the quality is basically like recording a video on the phone. I have found plenty of apps that can do this, but the bitrate and resolution is so low, that I can barely see myself in the video stream. It is really bad.

Comment: @New-To-IT: It can be paid.. sure. I'd rather not list all the apps. You can find them all on Google Play Store.

Comment: @New-To-IT How would listing all the apps I've tried help, when they don't offer what I want? I don't expect people to go out and search for apps for me, because I can do that fine myself.

Comment: @New-To-IT - Would people suggest me apps they aren't sure works? All requirements are: USB and 4K. That's literally all. If people suggest anything else they haven't tested or read the description of, I will report them. I listed my requirements. If you *think* you got the right app, go read the description. If it says USB and 4K, go post it in here. Otherwise it's a waste of everybody's time, don't you agree?

Comment: @New-To-IT "maybe the app worked for them, but it's not up to your standards" - Then why bother posting it, if I know it won't do 4K over USB? I honestly cannot see ANY reason, why I would list ALL the apps I have tried, which I KNOW for SURE won't work, because they DO NOT have 4K nor USB support. Give me ONE good reason why I should waste my time posting something THAT useless.

Comment: Any luck?  I'm looking for a similar app.  No USB webcams exist (that I can find) that offer true native resolutions higher than 1080p.  Some will advertise they do, but it ends up being some software up-conversion in the end.  I'm not sure if there's a limitation on the PC or something, but I would like a native resolution from a "USB Webcam" (or a virtual one that uses a smartphone over Wifi or USB) higher than 1080p.  thanks