# Use iPhone as WebCam for PC

Tags: gratis, mobile, camera

There are a lot of apps out there that allow you to use your phone as a WebCam and I don't know how to choose, and I'd like to solve this problem by delegating it to someone else. The app must be free as in gratis, able to use my iPhone camera, and bonus points if it is free as in libre and supports USB/Thunderbolt.

This is not a duplicate of [App that can use my Android phone as a webcam on my PC, but stream it in 4K over USB?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27416/app-that-can-use-my-android-phone-as-a-webcam-on-my-pc-but-stream-it-in-4k-over) as that one specifically wants USB. As much as I think that would satisfy my demands, that question doesn't have an answer, and I think this question is different enough.

Comment: I guess that by *PC*, you mean a Windows PC, not MacOs or Linux. Better to detail it in the post.

Comment: No, I meant any PC. macOS and Linux are also good.